# How to replace the '/' character using vi

Tags: regex, vim, replace, vi

What substitution command should I use, in order to replace every occurrence of the character `/` with the string "abc" in a text file with vi?

```
:1,$ s/?/abc
```

What should I use instead of the `?` in the above snippet?

Comment: try . . . .`%:s#/#abc#`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the substitution delimiter which is by convention `/` to something else then you would not have to escape the forward slash at all -

```
:%s;/;abc;g
:%s~/~abc~g
:%s!/!abc!g
:1,$s?/?abc?g
:%s/\//abc/g
:1,$sub;/;abc;g
```

These all do the same replacement of `/` with `abc` on every line.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is `:%s/\//abc/g` I think.

Comment: `:%s/\//abc/g` since OP is asking `to replace every occurrence of the character /`